# Is there a way to have a single icon along a way?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

I'm using a `MGLSymbolStyleLayer` to render icons on a way on my mapbox instance on iOS.
My problem right now is the frequency that icon is drawn: I tried all the values of MGLSymbolPlacement as value for `styleLayer.symbolPlacement` but none of them seems to satisfy my needs.
As you can see in the two attached images sometimes the red X are placed once along the way, sometimes more than once.
Using MGLSymbolPlacement.Point I achieved to have a single X on a way, but it would only be at its beginning.

My goal is to have a single X on each Way and placed at its middle point, half way between start and end.
Is it achievable in any way?

Thanks

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA5EJ.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v70t7.png)

```
let styleLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: identifier, source: source)
    styleLayer.sourceLayerIdentifier = sourceLayerIdentifier

    styleLayer.symbolPlacement = NSExpression(forConstantValue: MGLSymbolPlacement.line.rawValue)
    styleLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: imageName)
    styleLayer.iconScale =
        NSExpression(format: "mgl_interpolate:withCurveType:parameters:stops:($zoomLevel, 'linear', nil, %@)",
                     [13: 0.0, 15: 0.45])
    styleLayer.iconRotationAlignment = NSExpression(forConstantValue: MGLIconRotationAlignment.viewport.rawValue)
    styleLayer.iconAllowsOverlap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: true)
    styleLayer.keepsIconUpright = NSExpression(forConstantValue: true)
    styleLayer.iconOpacity =
        NSExpression(format: "mgl_interpolate:withCurveType:parameters:stops:($zoomLevel, 'linear', nil, %@)",
                     [13: 0, 14: 1])
```

Comment: Hi guys, 

any chance to have some help about this?